# Google Colab poor image quality

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Images in Colab look like smudged Minecraft - why, and how to fix? See reproducible example below - but differences are more pronounced on subplot grids and other visualizations, omitted for simplicity.

Both use a matplotlib inline backend - though Colab clearly uses a different variant of the graphical backend, which may be changeable.

---

**Browsers tested**: Firefox Developer Edition v71.0b12 x64; Google Chrome v78.0.3904.108 x64

**System**: Win-10 Home OS x64

---

[image]

[image]

---

**Reproducible code**: (hands not included)

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 80

img = np.random.randn(100, 100)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='bwr')
# used different values to make sizes match by actual pixel area
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 5)      # COLAB
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6.6, 6.6)  # SPYDER
```

Comment: The culprit may lie in the sentence *"used different values in Spyder vs. Colab to make sizes match by actual pixel area"*. So please show the exact output from each of the cases (not a montage), and show the exact values you used for producing them.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Not the culprit - I tried both with same values and with no values (omitting `plt.gcf()...`); the fairest comparison should be with both displaying the same number of pixels (otherwise, Colab looks even _worse_, as it tends to produce larger images w/ more smudge)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest As trying every reasonable combination (same pixels, no settings, larger, smaller) and getting the same result contradicts your suggestion - yes, your suggestion is invalidated

Comment: My suggestion was simply to show the actual output and the values used for producing those. Because that would allow to reproduce and compare and interprete. I didn't suggest a reason or solution yet.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Likewise I simply rejected the suggestion that `plt.gcf()...` was the culprit per my tests - but on showing the exact values used, good call; updated. (Again, I've tried greater/lesser values for each, Colab's quality still remains poorer than Spyder's)

Comment: So it seems one of those (or both) are ignoring the dpi setting. Without the actual output (no montage) I cannot find out which one it is. (In general, please either ignore a comment, or do what it suggests - but don't endlessly discuss about it)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I didn't ignore it, these are unedited outputs according exactly to code (and each's `plt.gcf()`) - and I tried without `dpi` also, same results. If by "no montage" you mean "don't use `plt.gcf()` and don't use `dpi`", can do, but the problem persists: Colab images are _blurry_.

Comment: The images are not the original output (that would give four images without further texts etc.) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomontage) Since I now spend already half the time I would usually take to solve a problem here on discussing, my involvement with this question will now need to end here. Sorry.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, I put them side-by-side for easier viewing, but that doesn't change how they look, and StackOverflow preprocesses images anyway, so I really don't see the need - but if you insist, updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**, sort of: zoom out to 80%. Why? Don't know - Colab-side shortcomings in web design.

[image]